# css grid auto-rows, wrap rows, auto-flow column or flexbox?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am building a grid with dynamic columns and dynamic rows.

Row height should always be 25vh.

Rows should be auto filled with a diverse pool of images.

Image height should be 100% of the row's height (==25vh) and should keep their aspect ratio, so their width depends on their height.

So the umber of images per row is dynamic and depends on image width, which depends on image height (==25vh).

Finally the grid should ideally be 'column dense' as in trying to force fill rows, by adding as many columns as necessary.

Here is my attempt:

```css
.mygrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 25vh; /* unlimited rows with a height of 25vh */
  grid-auto-flow: column dense; /* add columns as necessary, try to leave no holes  */
}
img {
  height: 100% /* occupy 100% of row height (25vh) */
}
```

This works, except that all images are placed in a single row, without wrapping down to new rows.

Setting .mygrid width to 100% or 100vw does not change this.

Full snippet:

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
}

.mygrid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 25vh;
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="mygrid">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/350">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/100">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/320">
  </div>

</div>
```

I am not sure why is this happens, and if it possible to achieve what I want with css grid.

I also considered using a flexbox container that wraps down to additional rows when necessary, bus afaik flexbox does NOT have a 'column dense' equivalent, so I would say there is no way for me to force fill rows, without resorting to JS.

Thanks

Comment: what you need, as you said the full snippet works in 1 line,25vh height what more?

Comment: I don't want images to exceed window width, I want them to wrap down to a new row

Comment: does this answer your question? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Auto-placement_in_CSS_Grid_Layout#use_cases_for_auto-placement

Comment: @Lalalena as far as I understand the width of the images do not depend on their height, but is explicitly specified (in a manner I don't fully understand) by the combination of repeat(auto-fill, minmax(x,y)) and span: 2 on .landscape

Comment: i have posted answer please look into it

Comment: @Neptotech-vishnu Thank you, as mentioned I want rows to be full without gaps. That is why I wanted to use grid-auto-flow: dense or column dense ; your solution leaves gaps at the end of the rows

Comment: its default in all code logically, think if sum of width of images is only 80% and for second row there is a image with 30% width it cant go to first row as first row can only support 20% ,so that 20% is empty u cant do anything.

Comment: @Neptotech-vishnu what about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow

Comment: please **try to understand logic** no code can do so it **depends on image**, code can-reduce left over space to the *minimum* **but not fully**

Comment: its like division,if length of all images(sum) is `divisible by 100%(total width)` it works,else the remainder creates left over space

Comment: grid auto flow is for grid,now forget that,you have three images [`a,b,c`], the widths are [`100px,250px,450px`] respectively&height is 25px for all images,now you have a box ( `mygrid` in your case) with width of `500px` ,  **forgot the code take a paper** and find which image will be in each line, **will  rows be full without gaps?**, *answer: no there will be gaps and I will align image `c in first line` , `a&b in second` line (first line have 500-450=50px gap)*

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  
}

.mygrid {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;/*here we use inline-block*/
  height: 25vh;
  
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  
}
body{
overflow-x: hidden;/*works without this also but doing so will remove the unwanted x scrollbar*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="mygrid">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/350">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/100">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/320">
  </div>

</div>
```

> Here we use inline block